# How to pull specific parts of a list on each line?

Tags: python

I have a list that spits out information like this: `['username', 'password'], ['username', 'password'], ['username', 'password']`, and so on..

I would like to be able to pull a specific username and password later on. 
For example:
`['abc', '9876'], ['xyz', '1234']`

**pull `abc` and tell them the password is `9876`.
Then pull `xyz` and tell them the password is `1234`**

I tried messing around with the list and I am just drawing a blank on how to do this.

```
    lines = []
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if 'Success' in line:
                #get rid of everything after word success so only username and password is printed out
                lines.append(line[:line.find("Success")-1])
    for element in lines:
        #split username and password up at : so they are separate entities
        #original output was username:password, want it to be username, password
        parts = element.strip().split(":")
        print(parts)
```

I want to pull each username and then pull their password as described above

Current output after running through this is `['username', 'password']`. The original output file had extra information that I got rid of which is what the code involving 'Success' took care of

**I would like to do this without hardcoding a username in to it. I am trying to automate this process so that it runs through every username and formats it to say, `"hi [username}, your password is [123]"`, for all of the usernames**

**I then later would like to be able to only tell the specific user their password. For example, i want to send an email to user abc. that email should only contain the username and password of user abc**

Comment: Is success the keyword before the line is shown? That is before each instance of the username:password success is before it?

Comment: Coming out of the text file, the output looked like this: [username, password, Success, Info]. I cut out success and everything following because I only wanted the username and password for what I am trying to do

Comment: Can you post the output in your question? And not the comments

Comment: the current output is listed in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly parts is the list that contains [Username:Password]. If that is the case we can assign each value of parts which should only have 2 elements in it to a dictionary as a dictionary pair and then call the username later on.

```
lines = []
User_Pass = {}
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if 'Success' in line:
                #get rid of everything after word success so only username and password is printed out
                lines.append(line[:line.find("Success")-1])
    for element in lines:
        #split username and password up at : so they are separate entities
        parts = element.strip().split(":")
        User_Pass.update({parts[0] : parts[1]})
```

Then you can call the password from the username as follows if you know the username:

```
 x = User_Pass["foo"]
```

Or as you stated in the comments:

```
for key, value in User_Pass.items():
    print('Username ' + key + ' Has a Password of ' + value)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding a username in to it? I am trying to automate this process so that it runs through every username and formats it to say, "hi [username}, your password is [123]", for all of the usernames

Comment: Yes. I'll update below. Can you add that to your question however. The way it is structured it makes it seem that you want to call it in the future.

Comment: are you trying to do `dict([['abc', '9876'], ['xyz', '1234']]).get('xyz')`??

Comment: without hardcording. `for i in data: print(f'hi {i[0]} your password is {i[1]}')`

Comment: Onyambu yes that is what i am trying to do but it is not calling the index it is just printing {i[0]}

Comment: I will! one more question: is there any way to just acces one username? currently they are all printing out. I am trying to make it so that only the username that matches with their email address prints out output you provided. so if my email was abc@test.com, i would only want to return the username and password for username 'abc'

Comment: Give me a few mins. I’ll update. Please add that to the question also.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing `parts`, append them to a list.

```
data = []
for element in lines:
    parts = element.strip().split(":")
    data.append(parts)
```

Then you could convert these into a dictionary for lookup

```
username_passwords = dict(data)
print(username_passwords['abc'])
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding a username in to it? I am trying to automate this process so that it runs through every username and formats it to say, "hi [username}, your password is [123]", for all of the usernames

Answer (score 0):

it looks like after you do this

```
lines.append(line[:line.find("Success")-1])
```

lines = ['username:password', 'username:password'...]

so I would do this

```
new_list_of_lists = [element.strip().split(":") for element in lines]
```

new_list_of_lists should now look like [[username, password], [username, password]]

then just do this:

```
dict_of_usernames_and_passwords = dict(new_list_of_lists)
```

with a dict you can have now retrieve passwords using usernames. like:

```
dict_of_usernames_and_passwords['abc']
```

you can save the dict, using json module, to a file, for easy retrieval.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding a username in to it? I am trying to automate this process so that it runs through every username and formats it to say, "hi [username}, your password is [123]", for all of the usernames

Comment: for username in dict_of_usernames_and_passwords:
   print(f"hi {username}, your password is {dict_of_usernames_and_passwords[username]}"